# What statistical analysis to use to compare two measurment tools of creativity?

Tags: statistical-significance, measurement, method-comparison

Participants took two different creativity assessment test. I al trying to make a comparison between the two measurment tools and see which one gives more insight about the level of creativity. 
What statistical analysis should I be using?

Comment: You could start by assessing the internal consistency of the two measurements, say by Cronbach alpha